# How to setup Angular environment variables for Heroku to patch during deployment?

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment, environment-variables

I have a Angular + Spring boot application that is deployed on Heroku.

- To setup environment variables at Spring for Heroku to patch, I just have to declare `spring.datasource.username=` inside the application-prod.properties and fill up the information at Heroku Config Vars.
- ***Question*** : How should I do this for the Angular's environment variable inside the environment-prod.ts so that the Heroku can patch the value into it during deployment? An example would be great.

Thanks.